# Find a substring in a column value from a list in another Table in PowerBI using power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Hi I'm trying to match a list of strings which is in a table to a column in another table which are file names. for example

| table2.column1 |
| --- |
| apple |
| pear |
| berry |
| orange |

| table1.column1 | table1.Colum2 |
| --- | --- |
| The guy with the apple | apple |
| the boy has an apple | apple |
| The dog has a berry | berry |
| the girl went to get an orange | orange |
| an apple a day | apple |

This is what its should look like in the end. in code I would just do this,

```
let stringName = table1.ColumnName
let siteName = table2.ColumnName
let matchcolumn = []

stringName.foreach((element) => {
 
 siteName.foreach((site) => {
     if(element.includes(site)){
         matchcolumn.push(site)
     }else{}
 })
})
```

can anyone tell me how i would do it in the powerbi query editor.

Answer (score 0):

In powerquery, create a lookup table with keywords to search for loaded as **Table2**

Create a table with a column to look up, here **Column1**

Use code below to find matches from Table2 against Column1 of Table1

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each  Text.Combine( List.Select(Table2[keyword], (x) => Text.Contains([Column1], x, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)), ", "))
in #"Added Custom"
```

[image]